# Unlocking Sony Xperia Z3 Compact with gloves

Tags: touchscreen, sony-xperia-z

I've read that, if I turn on Glove mode, it will increase sensitivity of touch if I unlock my phone with gloves on. But it is not working like that. Since I'll turn Glove mode on it has increased sensitivity no matter if I have gloves on or not.

Is it possible to do it so it would increase sensitivity only if I'll UNLOCK screen with gloves on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure there's not a misunderstanding here?

Comment: I found it on several pages: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2313539 "unlock the screen wearing gloves
if you want to exit glove mode just unlock the screen without gloves" http://www.phonearena.com/news/Glove-Mode-makes-the-Sony-Xperia-sola-perfect-for-cold-weather-climates_id35036 "Glove Mode automatically turns on when you unlock the handset wearing gloves" http://www.xperiablog.net/2012/09/28/glove-mode-demoed-on-the-xperia-sola-video/ " If you unlock the phone with a glove, floating touch mode is disabled and normal touch is enabled"

Comment: okay, I was just a bit sceptical, since I had never seen such a feature before in my life